Проваливание промиса
Всем добрый день, проблема с пониманием термина "проваливание промиса" и с решением двух задач. Если что-то приходит .then() отличное от функции,например .then(console.log("4")), то это считывается, как .then(null), но что происходит дальше? Этот then перемещается вверх в микротасках или работает как синхронный код?


const foo = async() => {
  console.log('1');
  return 100;
}

const bar = async() => {
  console.log('2');
  const r = await foo();
  console.log(r);
  foo().then((res) => console.log(res))
  await console.log('3');
  console.log(await '4');
}

bar()
//Ответ: 2 1 100 1 3 100 4



Почему в этом примере кода "3" всплывает, а "4" нет


console.log('this is the start');

Promise.resolve(console.log('promise 1')); //Почему этот консоль лог выполняется как синхронный?

setTimeout(function cb1() {
  console.log("timeout 0");
}, 2000)

setTimeout(function cb() {
  console.log("timeout 1");
})

console.log('this is just a message');

setTimeout(function cb1() {
  console.log('timeout 2')
}, 0);

new Promise((res, rj) => res('promise 2')).then(console.log)

console.log('this is the end?')



Почему тут Promise.resolve(console.log('promise 1')); Проблема с пониманием этой строчки.

".then(console.log("4")), то это считывается, как .then(null)," - нет. Это выводит 4  в консоли и возвращает undefined. А этот undefined возвращается в синхронный код как Promise<undefined>

@eccs0103 а что происходи при promise? Какое поведение у promise в цеопчке промисов? Почему тогда в первой задачи с async/await console.log(await '4'); - не синхронный код?

@eccs0103 это не Promise<undefined>. Если в then передали не функцию, то она заменяется на функцию function(x) { return x }. Т.е. p.then(console.log("4")) равносильно p.then(function(x){return x}) (ну и 4 выведет по дороге)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#onfulfilled

@AlexeyTen объясни еще пожалуйста первый блок кода await console.log('3'); и
console.log(await '4'); Почему в этом коде 3 всплывает, а 4 нет?

@AlexeyTen и я об этом. .then(console.log(4)) заменяется на .then((x) => console.log(4)), который выводит 4 и возвращяет undefined. То есть .then((x) => undefined), что и ровно Promise<undefined>. Я ничего неправильного не сказал.

«.then(console.log(4)) заменяется на .then((x) => console.log(4)» — нет. Выполняется (синхронно) console.log(4), выводит 4 и возвращает undefined и .then(undefined) заменяется на then((x)=>x)

@AlexeyTen и собственно как заменить undefined на (x) => x?

@eccs0103 что значить как заменить? Никак не надо заменять, js это сам сделает

@AlexeyTen конвертация из undefined в (x) => x я не представляю, даже со стороны JS-а

@eccs0103 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#onfulfilled «If it is not a function, it is internally replaced with an identity function ((x) => x) which simply passes the fulfillment value forward.»
